# Uma duvida sobre Layout em android kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um app de Delivery e queria fazer um layout legal e para isso olhei os layouts dos app que ja existem e vi que um tipo de tela para os produtos da loja que achei muito agradavel aos olhos e tambem funcional porem nao sei como montar ela sei quais componentes existem na tela mas nao sei como dar a devida funcionalidade a ela, vou postar uma foto para ficar mais clara a minha pergunta.

[image: Esta seria a tela que quero fazer, montei ela do Adobe XD]

Montei a tela no Adobe XD me baseando nas telas que vi sei que preciso de uma recycler View, uma image view e tambem de um tabView para as categorias porem quando eu desse scroll para baixo na tela tudo a cima do Tab View iria subir e o tab View ficaria fixo no topo para que o usuario pudesse trocar de categoria sem precisar dar scroll para cima, nao sei se conseguir ser claro na minha pergunta, mas gostaria apenas que me dessem uma luz para o problema, se algo na ficou claro posso tentar esclarecer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso se interesse pelo problema, encontrei uma solução o nome é Scrolling Header with Tabs, que e fixar o tab view quando vc da scroll, no fim eu nao fiz com tab layout nao consegui adicionar as tabelas em cima sem adicionar um fragment, entao fiz com recycler view e usei o Nasted Scroll view e adicionei essa linha nos elementos que eu queria que desaparecessem

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar todo o conteúdo que deseja "scrollar" em um único recyclerview, e colocar esse mesmo em um NestedScroolView, assim, ele vai rolar somente o Conteúdo especifico.